# How do I combine word wrap and dynamic font size in an WPF ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

The recommendations I see for the individual items are to use a `TextBlock` with `TextWrapping="true"` for for former, and a `Viewbox` for the latter.  However the two don't play nicely together.  The only one I've seen for combining the two was to explicitly set a [`Width` on the `TextBlock][1]`, but that requires knowing the width of the text in advanced because different lengths of text only work out nicely with different widths making in unsuitable for use with templating because the ideal length will be variable and not known in advance.

Without setting an explicit width what I get is:

[image]

Which works OK for the two single word items, but the multi-word one would fill the area much better if wrapped over multiple lines.

Setting `Width="80"` on the `TextBlock` gets the multi-word text to wrap nicely; but screws up the layout of single word items.

[image]

What I'd like is something that scales single word elements to fit (like the first two buttons in the top image) and wraps multiple word items prior to scaling to make better use of the available space (similar to the third button in the second example - although there's no need to limit it to only two rows of text if 3 or more would work better).

My XAML used for the examples above is:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MYViewModel x:Key="myVM"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource myVM}}">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ThingsList, Mode= OneWay}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="1"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button>
                        <Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And behind it:

```
public class NamedThing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MYViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<NamedThing> ThingsList { get; set; }
         = new ObservableCollection<NamedThing>
        {
            new NamedThing {Name = "Short"},
            new NamedThing {Name = "VeryVeryLongWord"},
            new NamedThing {Name = "Several Words in a Row"}
        };
}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a wild idea, what about using a converter to split your multi-words string in multiple one-word strings, and putting them in some kind of StackPanel inside your ViewBox? I've never used ViewBox, so I don't know it it'd work, but it could be a trail to follow.

Comment: @Kilazur that's far enough beyond anything I've done so far that I'm not sure how I'd go about approaching an attempt.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your Viewbox scale whatever is inside it, but the TextBlocks don't know in what they are contained and just grow (width wise) as much as they're allowed to (which is `Infinity` by default).

A first and quick solution is to set a `MaxWidth` (100, for example) value to the `TextBlock`. This way, the multi-word `TextBlock` will simply react exactly as the single-word ones: it will grow and shrink, but the word wrapping won't change.

The reason `MaxWidth` works and not `Width` is logically obvious when you know how Viewbox works: single words TextBlocks are smaller, so their `Width` is smaller, so they grow much more in a Viewbox than their multi-words counterparts, making them appear in a bigger font.

---

Expanding on this solution, you can bind MaxWidth to one of the TextBlock's parent's MaxWidth to have a evolving word-wrapping when the window is resized. You can then add a converter that will modify the value (like, divide it by 2) if you feel like the multi-word `TextBlock` doesn't take enough vertical space.

Code-behind converter:

```
public class WidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double)value) / 2.0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double)value) * 2.0;
    }
}
```

XAML resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MYViewModel x:Key="myVM" />
    <local:WidthConverter x:Key="wc" />
</Window.Resources>
```

MaxWidth:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
    MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource wc}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
    Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

---

The following example is a bit more complicated and more 'proof-of-concept' than solution; we split the multi-words with a converter to display each single word in a slot of a templated UniformGrid; the behavior seems more natural, but the layout of multi-word strings is kind of gross.

[image]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="150"
        Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MYViewModel x:Key="myVM" />
        <local:ThingConverter x:Key="tc" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource myVM}}">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ThingsList, Mode= OneWay}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="3"
                                 Rows="1"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button>
                        <Viewbox>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource tc}}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <UniformGrid />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   TextAlignment="Center"
                                                   Text="{Binding}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class ThingConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new List<string>(((NamedThing)value).Name.Split(' '));
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((List<string>)value).Aggregate((s, ss) => s + " " + ss);
        }
    }

    public class NamedThing
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class MYViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<NamedThing> ThingsList { get; set; }

        public MYViewModel()
        {
            ThingsList = new ObservableCollection<NamedThing>
            {
                new NamedThing {Name = "Short"},
                new NamedThing {Name = "VeryVeryLongWord"},
                new NamedThing {Name = "Several Words in a Row"}
            };
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll fiddle with that to see if I can get something reasonable looking out out, what I'd like would be something similar to the first image for the first two buttons and the second image for the 3rd.

Comment: @Dan I added a simpler solution (and explanation), just set your `TextBlock`'s MaxWidth property to something that pleases your eyes (100 seems to work nicely).

Comment: That's a definite step in the right direction and is better than what I had before; but splitting "several words in a row" between "a" and "row" isn't that great either.

Comment: That's sadly out of control with this solution, since this is how WPF wraps words

Comment: That's disappointing.  The sad bit is that if I was working on something legacy I do know enough about the gory details of overriding `OnPaint()` to do exactly what I want and have it place nicely with resizing on a winforms control.  *sigh*

Comment: Thinking a bit more, something similar to your original idea, but with a `StackPanel` for the innermost template instead of a `UniformGrid` and a "smart" string splitter that chopped longer strings into two or more similar length pieces might do the trick reasonably well without going too far down the rabbit hole.